# commas in between data cells not quoted load to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, csv

read a comma-separated CSV file with commas in cells has no quotes in python
For example the CSV file is in the below format

```
product,unit,count,alter,denom

(any name) xyz,kg,1,000,volume,1

reposting with data

read a comma separated csv file with commas in cells has no quotes in python example the csv file is in below format

product,unit,count,alter,denom

(any name or id) xyz,kg,1,000,volume,1

1142,KG,1,000,L,910

 1143,v,1,000,L,910

 11144,K,1,EA,1

 11529,KG,1,EA,1

 11548,V,1,EA,10

 11551,V,1,EA,4

 11562,K,1,000,TO,1

 11567,K,28,EA,100

 11569,v,1,000,TO,1

here count value is 1,000 but it is separated by comma which gives 2 values this should be rectified and load data to dataframes output should be like

product unit count alter denom

xyz kg 1,000 volume 1

i have used

df=pd.read_csv("filename.csv",sep=",")
```

here count value is 1,000 but it is separated by a comma which gives 2 values
this should be rectified and load data to data frames
the output should be like

```
product unit count alter   denom

xyz     kg  1,000 volume  1

1142    KG  1,000   L     910
```

I have used

```
df=pd.read_csv("filename.csv",sep=",")
```

Comment: is there any example how to perform it or can we use regex to get data as follows

Comment: 1142,KG,1,000,L,910 end of line
1143,v,1,000,L,910  end of line
11144,K,1,EA,1  end of line
11529,KG,1,EA,1  end of line
11548,V,1,EA,10  end of line
11551,V,1,EA,4  end of line
11562,K,1,000,TO,1  end of line
11567,K,28,EA,100  end of line
11569,v,1,000,TO,1 end of line like this data will be

Comment: now can you provide with example

Comment: @dummy You need to [edit] your question (as they explained above), *not* post an answer. The answer section is meant for answers, not revisions of your question. Press the [edit] link or the edit button below your question to add the information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that your input is not a valid `.csv` file. Either a comma is part of the data or it is a field delimiter. It can't be both.

The simplest approach is to go back to whoever or whatever supplied the file and complain that the format is invalid.

The producer of the file has several, usually easy, options to fix this: (1) Suppress the thousands separator. (2) Quote the field containing the comma, for example `"1,000"`. (3) Choose a different field delimiter, such as `;`. This is a very common approach in Europe because `,` frequently means a decimal point and so ignoring it is a bad idea.

You should not be in the position of having to clean up someone else's sloppy export.

However, since you have the file that you have, and don't seem in a position to take this advice, your only option is to reprocess the file so that it is valid.

The approach is to read the defective input file, check each row to see how many fields it has, and if it has one too many and the cause is a thousands separator comma masquerading as a field delimiter, then glue the two halves of the number back together; and then write out the modified file.

```
# fixit.py
# Program to accept an invalid csv file with an unescaped comma in column 3 and regularize it
# Use like this: python fixit.py < wrongfile.csv > rightfile.csv

import sys
import csv


def fix(row: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    """
    If there are 5 columns:
        return unchanged.
    If there are 6 columns
    and columns 2 and 3 can be interpreted as a number with a thousand separator:
        combine columns 2 and 3 and return the row.
    Otherwise return an empty list.
    """
    if len(row) == 5:
        return row
    if len(row) == 6 and row[2].isdigit() and row[3].isdigit():
        return row[:2] + [row[2] + row[3]] + row[4:]
    return []


def main(infile, outfile):
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        if fixed_row := fix(row):
            writer.writerow(fixed_row)
        else:
            print(f"Line {reader.line_num} could not be fixed", file=sys.stderr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout.reconfigure(newline="")
    # This is because module csv does its own thing with end-of-line and requires the file have newline=""
    main(sys.stdin,sys.stdout)
```

Given this input:

```
product,unit,count,alter,denom
(any name or id) xyz,kg,1,000,volume,11142,KG,1,000,L,910
 1143,v,1,000,L,910
 11144,K,1,EA,1
 11529,KG,1,EA,1
 11548,V,1,EA,10
 11551,V,1,EA,4
 11562,K,1,000,TO,1
 11567,K,28,EA,100
 11569,v,1,000,TO,1
```

you will see this output:

```
product,unit,count,alter,denom
 1143,v,1000,L,910
 11144,K,1,EA,1
 11529,KG,1,EA,1
 11548,V,1,EA,10
 11551,V,1,EA,4
 11562,K,1000,TO,1
 11567,K,28,EA,100
 11569,v,1000,TO,1
```

along with a warning written to the console about line 2.

Your question shows the data with a blank line between each row of data. I'm assuming that your data is not really like that and the blank lines are the result of your inexperience in formatting a Stack Overflow question properly. But if your data really is like that, the program will still work. You will just get a lot of warnings about blank lines. There won't be any blank lines in the output because `pandas.read_csv()` doesn't need them.